# Phalcon\Loader\Loader not found

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a newly cloned phalcon repository:

```
software: MacOS
Phalcon: 5.0.0RC4
PHP: 8.1
Zephir: 0.16.0
brew: phalcon@4.1.0
Location: ~/Documents/cphalcon
```

I am trying to set up my new repository by following the tutorial [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/tutorial-basic).
However when I go to my page at localhost:8000, this error pops up:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Phalcon\Loader\Loader" not found in /Users/apple/Documents/cphalcon/public/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /Users/apple/Documents/cphalcon/.htrouter.php(15): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /Users/apple/Documents/cphalcon/public/index.php on line 16
```

I found some similar thread and they said to check my phpinfo to see if phalcon is there, and it was.
I checked for more materials but couldn't find any other clues.
I also tried changing the call to:

```php
use Phalcon\Loader;
```

But it was the same

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Phalcon\Loader" not found in /Users/apple/Documents/cphalcon/public/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /Users/apple/Documents/cphalcon/.htrouter.php(15): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /Users/apple/Documents/cphalcon/public/index.php on line 16
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in version 5 the proper syntax now is Phalcon\Autoload\Loader().

Since Phalcon 5 is still in Release Candidate mode (hence the "RC4" on the version), the docs are still lagging a bit behind.

I've converted a couple of Phalcon 3 and 4 sites, and I found the [Phalcon 5.0.0RC4 ChangeLog](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/CHANGELOG-5.0.md) to be helpful when moving from Phalcon 4 to 5.  The move from 3 to 5 is far more involved and requires finding the Phalcon 4 update doc on the Phalcon web site.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't noticed the changelog, helps a lot :)

Answer (score -2):

There is a question.
which version of phalcon are you using? 5 or 4 ?
If 5 then use Phalcon\Autoload\Loader instead of Phalcon\Loader;
I hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).